# KDB split by fixed delimiter

Tags: kdb

I have a column with xmls

```
<Options TE="2017/09/01, 16:45:00.000" ST="2017/09/01, 09:00:00.000" TT="2017/09/01, 16:45:00.000"/>
<Options TE="2017/09/01, 16:45:00.000" ST="2017/09/01, 09:00:00.000" TT="2017/09/01, 16:45:00.000"/>
<Options TE="2017/09/04, 16:45:00.000" ST="2017/09/04, 09:00:00.000" TT="2017/09/04, 16:45:00.000"/>
```

That I am trying to split in columns

```
TE, ST, TT
```

The type of the data is C

Not very familiar with kdb/q I tried to go the very manual way. First removed the start and end tags

```
x:update `$ssr[;"<Options";""] each tags from x
x:update `$ssr[;"/>";""] each string tags from x
```

leaving me with rows like

```
TE="2017/09/01, 16:45:00.000" ST="2017/09/01, 09:00:00.000" TT="2017/09/01, 16:45:00.000"
```

Then, splitting the string

```
select `$"\"" vs' string tags from  x
```

gives me a list where the odd entries are my times. I just can't figure out how to take that list and split it into separate columns. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a slightly different approach but the following should do what you want:

```
//Clean the tags up for separation
//(get rid of open/close tags, change ", " to "," for ease of parsing and remove quote marks) 
x:update tags:{ssr/[x;("<Options ";"/>";", ";"\"");("";"";",";"")]} each tags from x


//Parse the various tags using 0:, put the result into a dictionary,
//exec out to table form and add to x
x:x,'exec (!) ./: ("S= " 0:/: tags) from x
```

For reference here's the table I used:

```
x:([] tags:("<Options TE=\"2017/09/01, 16:45:00.000\" ST=\"2017/09/01, 09:00:00.000\" TT=\"2017/09/01, 16:45:00.000\"/>";
"<Options TE=\"2017/09/01, 16:45:00.000\" ST=\"2017/09/01, 09:00:00.000\" TT=\"2017/09/01, 16:45:00.000\"/>";
"<Options TE=\"2017/09/04, 16:45:00.000\" ST=\"2017/09/04, 09:00:00.000\" TT=\"2017/09/04, 16:45:00.000\"/>"))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that worked. Not that I understand how, though. how does the part left of, inclusive ./: work?

Comment: 1.The `("S= " 0:/: tags)` gives a pair of lists where each row looks like so:
(`TE`ST`TT;(2017/09/01,16:45:00.000;2017/09/01,09:00:00.000;2017/09/01,16:45:00.000))`
2.`(!) ./:` changes the above into a dictionary for each row in the table. For the example row above, the dictionary looks like so:
`TE`ST`TT!2017/09/01,16:45:00.0002017/09/01,09:00:00.0002017/09/01,16:45:00.000`
3.`exec` will extract the list of dictionaries from the table.  The resulting list is itself an unkeyed table since (table <=> list of dictionaries)
4.`x,'` joins the resulting tables together at a row level

Comment: a, thanks a lot. Q sometimes doesn't seem less cryptic than the rosetta stone

Answer (score 0):

Crazy thought: Is your XML data **that** regular looking, so that one can select "columns" via indexing. If so, suppose the data (above) was in 3-element list of strings, is it not possible that you apply some function foo to:

```
foo xmllist[;ind]
```

where ind selects the data required. The function foo would do the necessary conversion to the timestamp datatype, either by using (types;delimiter) 0: ...  ?

Answer (score 0):

see if you can export XML file into JSON file.
kdb+/q has a json parser which does all the dirty work for you.
`.j.k` and `.j.j`.

Reference: http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/websockets/#json